# Android TCP/IP Client not work on real Device

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

this is a part of my Android tcp client , it's work perfect on Emulator , but when it run on my Samsung Galaxy S3 it's not work , i'm sure that my phone is connected to router via wifi , can i get some help please

```
class Connect_Thread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr , SERVERPORT);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please give some information. Do the exceptions get thrown? Have you made your manifest allow for network access?

Comment: thanks for reply , i called class in onCreate method
when the program is run on Samsung S3 there is no exceptions , and also there is no connect to the server , but in the Emulator the server tell me that's there 1 connection and every thing is awesome , if you want i'll put full code here .

Comment: private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.7";

Comment: Do you have a localhost web server running? If so can you open it up in your phone browser and make sure that the ip address is reachable from your phone?

Comment: yes i have wampserver and it's working , but i can't access to http:\\localhost from my phone browser ? any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues for your problem.

1) Your code above won't work via the phones internet connection (UMTS, GMRS) because it uses an IP from an IP pool reserved for [private networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)

2.) Make sure your Android Device and your server are in the same network. Routers often place WiFi/WLAN devices into a different network ([subnetwork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork)). i.e. LAN devices could get `192.168.1.0/255.255.255.128` will have ranges from `192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.126` while WLAN gets `192.168.1.128/255.255.255` assigned and has IP addresses from `192.168.1.129 to 192.168.1.254`.

3.) If you use a rooted Android devices you may be using an Android Firewall. In this case you will have to allow the App to use WiFi connection.

4.) Windows/PC Firewall. If you run a Windows or PC Firewall, make sure the Firewall is able to accept **incoming** connections on Port 80

In this case your Android device will be in a different network and you will have to add a new route in your router. Alternatively you can configure your router to use the same IP pool for WLAN and LAN.

Comment: yes i'm in the same network router , my phone ip is 192.168.1.5 and my PC ip that's have c# server is 192.168.1.7 , i don't understand why it's work on Emulator and not work on my phone , my PC have localhost server but i can't access to it via my phone also , when i type 192.168.1.7 in my phone browser i have error page , any idea please ?

Comment: I have added a 4th listing. Is your PC firewall enabled? If so, does it allow **incoming** connections on Port 80 (default HTTP port)? If not open this port

Comment: @RamzyAbuShaaban have you got any solution? I am getting the same issue in real device.

Answer (score 0):

Are your computer and mobile phone on the same network? Because, 192.168.1.7 is the local IP and so it might have worked in your emulator. But if the mobile is on the different network, it wont work.

Comment: Any exception is thrown?